# Regex, match year listed as range

Tags: r, regex, perl

I have a list of years like this:

```
2018-

2001–2020

1999-

2005-
```

I would like to create a regex to match the year with these criteria:

```
xxxx-     matches xxxx

yyyy-nnnn matches nnnn
```

Can you please help me?

I've tried `[[:digit:]]{4}$`, or alternatively `[[:digit:]]{4}-$`, but they only partially work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. This is what I expect:

2018 
2020
1999
2005

Comment: Are you using R or perl?

Answer (score 3):

To get the last year in the "range," established by `-` character, the cleanest way

```
my $year = (split /-/, $range)[-1];
```

If there isn't anything after the last delimiter then the last returned element by `split` is what is before it, so the last element in its return list (obtained with index `-1`) is either the second given year -- as in `2001-2020` -- or the only one, as in other examples. This performs no checking of input.

With a regex, one way is to seek the last number in the string

```
my ($year) = $range =~ /([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$/;
```

where if you use `[0-9]{4}` then there is a small additional measure of checking.

The POSIX [character class](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html) `[[:digit:]]` and its negation `[[:^digit:]]` (or `\P{PosixDigit}`) can be used instead if desired, but note that these match all manner of Unicode "digit characters," just like `\d` and `\D` do (a few hundred), on top of the ascii `[0-9]` (unless `/a` modifier is used).

A full test program, for both

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @ranges = qw(2018- 2001-2020 1999- 2005-);

foreach my $range (@ranges) { 
    my $year = (split /-/, $range)[-1];
    
    # Or, using regex
    # my ($year) = $range =~ /([0-9]+)[^0-9]*$/;
    
    say $year;
}
```

Prints as desired.

Answer (score 0):

We can capture the 4 digits as group, followed by a `-` at the end (`$`) of the string and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub(".*(\\d{4})-?$", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "2018" "2020" "1999" "2005"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("2018-", "2001-2020", "1999-", "2005-")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text on `"-"` and get the last number.

```
x <- c("2018-", "2001-2020", "1999-", "2005-")
sapply(strsplit(str1, '-', fixed = TRUE), tail, 1)
#[1] "2018" "2020" "1999" "2005"
```